# Why is my "Greatest Common Denominator" program not outputting the right information?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is my program to determine the "greatest common denominator of two numbers"

```
integer1 = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
integer2 = int(input("Enter an integer:"))

if integer1 > integer2:
    x = integer1
    while integer1%x and integer2%x !=0:
        x = x - 1

elif integer2 > integer1:
    x = integer2
    while integer1%x and integer2%x !=0:
        x = x - 1

print("the gcd of",integer1,"and",integer2,"is",x)
```

for example, when I input the values "25" and "50", my program will say the GCD is 50, which is incorrect.

Comment: By GCD do you mean the Greatest Common Divisor, the largest number that evenly divides to given numbers? That is the usual meaning, and for this meaning the GCD of 25 and 50 is 25. The Greatest Common Denominator is different: for 1/25 and 1/50 the greatest common denominator is indeed 50, since to add those two fractions you want to change both fractions to have a denominator of 50. If that's what you mean you should call it the Least Common Multiple (LCM).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Greatest common divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870995/greatest-common-divisor)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = min(integer1, integer2)
while integer1 % x or integer2 % x:
    x = x - 1
```

- avoid duplicating your code, just set `x` then apply your logic which doesn't change
- `x` can start at the minimum value rather than the maximum
- for `x` to be accepted it should satisfy both `integer1 % x == 0` and `integer2 % x == 0`, so the stop condition of your `while` should be `integer1 % x != 0 or integer2 % x != 0` (and the `!=0` are here redundant with int to bool conversion so you can skip them)
- in general `a and b == 0` type of expression don't behave the way you probably think, the "correct" way is `a == 0 and b == 0`.

Comment: This answer could really use some explanation.